# How to size a ContentDialog to use most of the space in the active window

Tags: uwp

I would like my `ContentDialog` to resize with my application window, and use most of the space (say 80%) of the hosting window.

I've tried to accomplish this with the following code, but it's not working:

```
        var windowSize = CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().Bounds;
        ContentDialog cd = new ContentDialog();
        {
            Width = windowSize.Width * .8,
            Height = windowSize.Height * .8,
            Content = new NewEditPage(),
            FullSizeDesired = true
        }
        await cd.ShowAsync();
```

I need the ContentDialog to resize with the window, so that if the user shrinks the window the ContentDialog should update to continue maintaining a height/width of 80%.

Answer (score 0):

You want to override the default style of the ContentDialog control first.

You can see following definitions from "https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299120.aspx"

```
<x:Double x:Key="ContentDialogMinWidth">320</x:Double>
<x:Double x:Key="ContentDialogMaxWidth">548</x:Double>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved the maximum width by the following:

```
        EditCartItemDialog ObjectEditCartDialog = new EditCartItemDialog(TempCartItem,_list_cart_items);
        ObjectEditCartDialog.MinWidth = this.ActualWidth;
        ObjectEditCartDialog.MaxWidth = this.ActualWidth;
```

Here EditCartItemDialog is a ContentDialog.
You can also achieve maximum height by the following

```
        ObjectEditCartDialog.MaxHeight = this.ActualHeight;
        ObjectEditCartDialog.MaxHeight = this.ActualHeight;
```

It will adjust itself if user shrinks the window.